# Solving a (fun!) coequalizer problem for $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ in $\mathbf{Grp}$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, linear-transformations, limits-colimits

First off, the problem posed below is mostly arbitrary; it's just for my own education. (And maybe for yours, as well.)

It's fairly clear to me what the (co)equalizers of abelian groups in $\mathbf{Grp}$ are, but it's less clear what those mean for non-abelian groups. So, I came up with a problem that seems non-trivial and interesting.

---

I'm trying to coequalize $f,g:\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})\rightrightarrows\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$, where

- $f(A)=A$
- $g(A)=(A^*)^{-1}$

(Both purposely *not* surjective.)

---

To solve this, we need to find "the best" $l:\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow L$. For now, I'll settle for *any* $L$ that isn't $\{0\}$.

The images of both $f$ and $g$ are $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})\subset\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$, so to start with I'll just look at that part of the domain of $l$.

- $l(A^*)=l(A^{-1})$, based on $f$ and $g$. (Again, just on $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ for now.)
- $l(AA^*)=l(A^*A)=e_L$, following from the statement above, and $l$ being a homomorphism.
- Since $AA^*$ and $A^*A$ are positive-definite Hermitian (PDH), and PDH have Cholesky decompositions resembling $AA^*$, we can more generally say that $l(B)=e_L$ when $B$ is PDH. (Extending $l$ to $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$.)
- This also means that $l(D)=e_L$ when $D$ is diagonal with positive entries.
- For any $A\in\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$, we can create an SVD $A=U\Sigma V^*$, with unitary $U$ and $V$, and $U,\Sigma,V\in\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$. Since $l(\Sigma)=e_L$, $l(A)=l(UV^*)$. ($UV^*$ should be unique, since $A$ is of full rank.)
- If $A$ is unitary, it can be diagonalized as $A=VDV^*$ for unitary $V$ and diagonal $D$. *Importantly*, $D$ should only be in the kernel of $l$ if it only has *positive* (real) values, which is only true for $I$.

So it seems like $L$ is (at most) isomorphic to $\mathrm{SU}(n)$, with $l(A)$ taking $A$ to an equivalence class based on its rotation action after removing any distortion it makes. Does that sound accurate and/or reasonable? (For example, maybe a matrix with a non-real determinant can sneak in when removing $\Sigma$, thereby breaking $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$.)

---

I spent several hours going through this, and I changed my conclusion about 5 times. The last few times were while proofreading. Whether or not my answer above is correct, I'd appreciate any pointers regarding shortcuts I could have taken, etc.

Comment: This isn’t that huge a deal, but $f$ and $g$ are anti-homomorphisms, right? They don’t technically lie in the category of groups.

Comment: The opposite of a monoid (regarded as a category) is still a monoid, right? So $f,g$ are contravariant functors.

Comment: What is $|A|$ ? Is it the determinant ?  If so, $|\frac{A}{|A|}| = \frac{|A|}{|A|^n}$ which is hardly ever $1$

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Good point. In all my haste thinking about solving the problem, I totally forgot that that's not how you normalize a matrix. But, since I'm not doing an equalizer, I just changed the domain to $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @KevinArlin I wasn't aware of antihomomorphisms! No wonder it was a mess when I tried to equalize $A$ and $A^*$ initially. I just moved the inverse from $f$ to $g$.

Comment: @Fosco It seems like the distinction is important if the codomains of $f$ and $g$ are in opposite groups, since (AFAIK) $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})\neq\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})^\mathrm{op}$.

Comment: I agree with you, sure; but at least the problem is well-posed, in some sense. :)

Comment: So the coequalizer is (isomorphic to) the quotient of $\operatorname{SL}_n(\Bbb{C})$ by the subgroup of all diagonalizable matrices with only positive real eigenvalues. What kind of description of this quotient are you looking for?

Comment: @Servaes It does look like that quotient is a reasonable description, *provided* my work is actually correct; I'm hoping to get more verification. In any case, I'd also like help relating the solution to the problem statement, just to get an idea of if it should have been obvious without a laborious derivation. In particular, it seems like it's always going to be a quotient over the kernel of some $h$, but for non-abelian groups, is there a simple rule for finding that $h$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coequalizer is trivial.

$SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is almost a simple group (for $n \ge 2$, and it's trivial for $n = 1$): its center $Z(SL_n(\mathbb{C}))$ is the subgroup of scalar multiples of the identity where the scalar is an $n^{th}$ root of unity, and the quotient by the center is the projective special linear group $PSL_n(\mathbb{C})$, which is simple (either as an abstract group or as a Lie group; for simplicity as an abstract group see, for example, [this note by Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/PSLnsimple.pdf)).

This implies that a normal subgroup containing any non-central element of $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ must in fact be all of $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$, which is certainly the case for the normal subgroup describing this coequalizer.

Answer (score 1):

In general the coequalizer of $f,g:\ H \longrightarrow\ K$ in $\mathbf{Grp}$ is (isomorphic to) the quotient $K/N$ where $N$ is the normal closure of
$$\{f(h)g(h)^{-1}:\ h\in H\}.\tag{1}$$
In this particular case we have $f(A)g^{-1}(A)=AA^{\ast}$, which is real symmetric and positive definite, so it orthogonally diagonalisable, i.e. $AA^{\ast}=Q_A^{-1}D_AQ_A$ for an orthogonal matrix $Q_A\in O_n(\Bbb{R})$ and a diagonal matrix $D_A\in\operatorname{SL}_n(\Bbb{R})$ with all diagonal entries positive. Note that we may also take $Q_A\in\operatorname{SL}_n(\Bbb{C})$ because a priori $\det Q_A=\pm1$, and hence also either either
$$Q_A\in\operatorname{SL}_n(\Bbb{C})\qquad\text{ or }\qquad \zeta_{2n}Q_A\in\operatorname{SL}_n(\Bbb{C}),$$
where $\zeta_{2n}$ is a primitive $n$-th root of $-1$, and of course $\zeta_{2n}Q_A$ also satisfies
$$(\zeta_{2n}Q_A)^{-1}D_A(\zeta_{2n}Q_A)=Q_A^{-1}D_AQ_A=AA^{\ast}.$$
Then the normalizer of $(1)$ contains
\begin{eqnarray*}
N&=&\{P^{-1}AA^{\ast}P:\ A\in\operatorname{SL}_n(\Bbb{R}),\ P\in\operatorname{SL}_n(\Bbb{C})\}.\\
&=&\{P^{-1}Q_A^{-1}D_AQ_AP:\ A\in\operatorname{SL}_n(\Bbb{R}),\ P\in\operatorname{SL}_n(\Bbb{C})\}.\\
&=&\{P^{-1}D_AP:\ A\in\operatorname{SL}_n(\Bbb{R}),\ P\in\operatorname{SL}_n(\Bbb{C})\}.\\
\end{eqnarray*}
So the coequalizer is precisely the quotient of $\operatorname{SL}_n(\Bbb{C})$ by the normal subgroup generated by all diagonalizable matrices with real positive eigenvalues, which seems like a big subgroup. Apparently this is all of $\operatorname{SL}_n(\Bbb{C})$, and so the coequalizer is trivial.

Comment: I posted this in a bit of a hurry because my battery will die in a minute. I will check the details in a few hours.

Comment: Thanks! Does this generalization easily follow from the axioms of $\mathbf{Grp}$? Also, does this imply that if one knows all of the normal subgroups of $G$ then one knows every potential coequalizer solution?

Comment: @Servaes: the subset of diagonalizable matrices with real positive eigenvalues isn't a subgroup. $SL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is very close to being a simple group and it has very few normal subgroups.

Comment: @Kevin: yes, it follows pretty easily, and yes, if you know all the normal subgroups of $G$ then this tells you all possible coequalizers.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You are absolutely right, I was a bit confused by the result myself when I posted this in a hurry. I have corrected this into a half-finished answer, as yours is more to the point anyway.